# Xib info window на картах

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, view

Я пытаюсь создать собственное информационное окно для маркеров на моей карте. Для этого я создал View.xib, чтобы настроить его так, как мне нужно, и я вызываю его из класса, в котором реализована карта. На карте отображаются два маркера, но безрезультатно, когда я нажимаю на маркеры. Как я могу правильно вызвать эту view на карте??

**MapView.swift**

```
class MapView: UIView,CLLocationManagerDelegate,GMSMapViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

let mapView = GMSMapView(frame: CGRect.zero,camera: GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20), zoom: 12))

var marker1 = GMSMarker()
var marker2 = GMSMarker()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    initView()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    initView()
}

private func initView() {
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MapView", owner: self, options: nil)
    contentView = mapView

    markers()

    addSubview(mapView)
    contentView.frame = self.bounds

    mapView.delegate = self 
}

func markers()
{
    marker1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.861, longitude: 151.20)
    marker1.map = mapView
    marker1.userData = ["marker": "1"]

    marker2.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.859, longitude: 151.21)
    marker2.map = mapView
    marker2.userData = ["marker": "2"]
}


func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {

    var markerData : [String:Any]?
    if let data = marker.userData as? [String:Any] {
        markerData = data
    }
    print(#function, "\(markerData?["marker"] as? String ?? "")")

    return true



    }
  func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {

        return UINib(nibName: "customInfoWindowView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! customInfoWindowView
    }


}
```

**customInfoWindowView.swift**

```
class customInfoWindowView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var contentView:UIView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initView()

    }

    private func initView() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("customInfoWindowView", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.frame = self.bounds

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно вернуть `false` из данного метода

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
        // ...
        return false
    }
```

В комментарии к методу сказано

> return YES if this delegate handled the tap event, which prevents the
>   map from performing its default selection behavior, and NO if the map
>   should continue with its default selection behavior.

Это значит, что нужно разрешить карте дальнейшую обработку события нажатия, после чего и будет вызван метод `func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView?`